# Python -- Find a sequence of numbers in triplets, quadruplets or more:

Tags: python, list, numbers, sequence

So, in my problem i have a list of numbers,i.e:

```
[0, 10, 11, 12, 24, 26, 28, 30, 31]
```

and i want to find a sequence of consecutive numbers in this list, in this case [10, 11, 12] my desired output is a tuple telling me the position of the first number in this sequence and how many numbers are in the sequence, generalized for a sequence of N numbers.

the output for the given sequence is equal to (2,3)

I've tried something like for sequences of 3:

```
#sequence of 3
for i in range(len(b)-3):
  if i>=2 and b[i]==b[i+1] and b[i]==b[i+2] and b[i]!=b[i-1] and b[i]!=b[i+3]:
    count_seq_3 += 1
    position_3= i
 print(position_3, count_seq_3)
```

The given output is (0,0) anyone could please help me in what is wrong? thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [0, 10, 11, 12, 24, 26, 28, 30, 31]
sequence = []
for i in range(len(list)-2):
    if list[i] == list[i+1] - 1 or list[i] == list[i-1] + 1:
        sequence.append(list[i])
print((list.index(sequence[0]), len(sequence)))
```

The actual output is:

```
(1, 3)
```

Where 1 is index of starting element 10 in your list and 3 is length of your sequence.